# Cannot access Pi through web browser after certain uptime

Tags: pi-3, wifi, apache-httpd

I have set up my Pi 3+ with an apache2 server, which works in my browser with both the IP and its hostname `raspberrypi.local`. I can also access the Pi through SSH. However, after some uptime (maybe a day) I cannot access it through the browser (tried Chrome and Edge) on my Windows PC with either `raspberrypi.local` or its IP. I can still access it with SSH (both with `raspberrypi.local` and the IP) and from my iPhone's browser. If I reboot the Pi, I can access it through my PC's browser again. All throughout, I also see it from my WiFi router.

What could the error be? It appears to be an error on my PC, but I have no clue where to start.

Comment: Welcome. You have not actually said what the state of the apache server is when this happens (which should be easy to check since you can ssh in).

Comment: The apache server is up all the time, and, as mentioned, I can access it on my mobile device's browser.

Comment: Sorry -- missed that.  As you remark, then, the error appears to be with the PC.  Have you tried any of the recommended tweaks with chrome to resolve local DNS issues?  Are you using DHCP or a static address with the Pi?  I think the browser(s) may be caching addresses and/or using their own DNS servers (keep in mind Edge is Chromium based).  I think you need to try (or explain how you have tried) flushing browser cache, etc.  Also, is the web server using TLS (ie., https)?

Comment: @goldilocks `caching addresses and/or using their own DNS servers` would not effect using the IP address, since that doesn't require DNS; and `raspberrypi.local` would be resolved using *mDNS*/*bonjour*/*avahi* or whatever its called

Comment: `tried Chrome and Edge` so, effectively tried the same pig with two shades of lipstick :p - try Firefox

Comment: Seems my reading skills really failed here -- in any case, you are still at the place you started from, and that's not just that it "appears to be an error on my PC", but that it rationally can't be with the Pi unless you have some problematic firewall configuration (which you don't mention any here).  Sans that, if other nodes can connect fine, and everything works except two variations on the same web browser running on one specific computer, you are barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: You should have a look at this in [wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark), to either confirm that there is no form of reply from the Pi, or to distinguish between the [three possible scenarios for the failure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73782/25985) if packets actually are reaching it. WRT to this, you should really edit into the question more specifically what you mean by "cannot access", since there are a number of possibilities there (does it just time out? what is the error message?) and these do reflect something about the nature of the problem.